# fabcar example: fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x63 pc=0x7f84bc4ea259]

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Env:

```sh
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
$ go version
go version go1.12 linux/amd64
$ docker -v
Docker version 18.09.4, build d14af54266
$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064
```

Getting started with hyperledger-fabric following the fabcar tutorial on [docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html).

In step - Launch the network - executing the start script `./startFabric.sh javascript` I get following output:

```sh
# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
Removing network net_basic

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com couchdb
Creating network "net_basic" with the default driver
Creating orderer.example.com ... done
Creating couchdb             ... done
Creating ca.example.com      ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                            NAMES
9c83dd6b6b42        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        1 second ago        Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
b5681dfbb92e        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   5 seconds ago       Up 1 second             4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
13bc657c24e8        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   5 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds            0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.example.com
205a84caf83a        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                5 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds            0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com

# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
#echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
Error response from daemon: Container 9c83dd6b6b42ba6ee984f28c94c3e2c0672f5af72def3a0807ff985609635a92 is not running
```

The peer0.org1.example.com container is created but not running.

```
$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                        NAMES
881d94d81fd6        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        20 seconds ago      Exited (2) 19 seconds ago                                                peer0.org1.example.com
5a090040c418        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   24 seconds ago      Up 20 seconds               4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp   couchdb
ed0d5717c386        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   24 seconds ago      Up 21 seconds               0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                       ca.example.com
59b703dd8d7b        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                24 seconds ago      Up 22 seconds               0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                       orderer.example.com
```

Listing container log for peer0.org1.example.com

```sh
$ docker logs peer0.org1.example.com 
2019-04-15 11:32:26.276 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 001 Starting peer:
 Version: 1.4.1
 Commit SHA: 87074a7
 Go version: go1.11.5
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Chaincode:
  Base Image Version: 0.4.15
  Base Docker Namespace: hyperledger
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger
2019-04-15 11:32:26.276 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 002 Initializing ledger mgmt
2019-04-15 11:32:26.276 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 003 Initializing ledger provider
2019-04-15 11:32:26.343 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 004 ledger provider Initialized
2019-04-15 11:32:26.473 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 005 Created state database _users
2019-04-15 11:32:26.497 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 006 Created state database _replicator
2019-04-15 11:32:26.497 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 007 ledger mgmt initialized
2019-04-15 11:32:26.498 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 008 Auto-detected peer address: 172.27.0.5:7051
2019-04-15 11:32:26.498 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 009 Returning peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2019-04-15 11:32:26.498 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 00a Auto-detected peer address: 172.27.0.5:7051
2019-04-15 11:32:26.498 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 00b Returning peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2019-04-15 11:32:26.500 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 00c Entering computeChaincodeEndpoint with peerHostname: peer0.org1.example.com
2019-04-15 11:32:26.500 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 00d Exit with ccEndpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7052
2019-04-15 11:32:26.501 UTC [nodeCmd] createChaincodeServer -> WARN 00e peer.chaincodeListenAddress is not set, using peer0.org1.example.com:7052
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x63 pc=0x7f84bc4ea259]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x1272c18, 0x2a)
    /opt/go/src/runtime/panic.go:608 +0x72
runtime.sigpanic()
    /opt/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:374 +0x2f2

goroutine 43 [syscall]:
runtime.cgocall(0xe455e0, 0xc000024e00, 0x29)
    /opt/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:128 +0x5e fp=0xc000024dc8 sp=0xc000024d90 pc=0x4039ee
net._C2func_getaddrinfo(0xc00014db60, 0x0, 0xc0003212f0, 0xc00039a178, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:91 +0x55 fp=0xc000024e00 sp=0xc000024dc8 pc=0x616c85
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME.func1(0xc00014db60, 0x0, 0xc0003212f0, 0xc00039a178, 0x17, 0x17, 0x65fb12980a82d3)
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:149 +0x131 fp=0xc000024e48 sp=0xc000024e00 pc=0x61c3b1
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME(0xc00014d860, 0x16, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:149 +0x153 fp=0xc000024f38 sp=0xc000024e48 pc=0x618243
net.cgoIPLookup(0xc00034cf00, 0xc00014d860, 0x16)
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:201 +0x4d fp=0xc000024fc8 sp=0xc000024f38 pc=0x6188fd
runtime.goexit()
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333 +0x1 fp=0xc000024fd0 sp=0xc000024fc8 pc=0x45de51
created by net.cgoLookupIP
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:211 +0xad

goroutine 1 [select]:
net.(*Resolver).LookupIPAddr(0x1fa0d00, 0x13b7a20, 0xc0000460a0, 0xc00014d860, 0x16, 0xc00014d877, 0x4, 0x1b8c, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/lookup.go:227 +0x55f
net.(*Resolver).internetAddrList(0x1fa0d00, 0x13b7a20, 0xc0000460a0, 0x123d330, 0x3, 0xc00014d860, 0x1b, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/go/src/net/ipsock.go:279 +0x614
net.(*Resolver).resolveAddrList(0x1fa0d00, 0x13b7a20, 0xc0000460a0, 0x124016e, 0x6, 0x123d330, 0x3, 0xc00014d860, 0x1b, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/go/src/net/dial.go:202 +0x4fb
net.(*ListenConfig).Listen(0xc000332fc8, 0x13b7a20, 0xc0000460a0, 0x123d330, 0x3, 0xc00014d860, 0x1b, 0xc0005506c0, 0x30, 0xc00009e700, ...)
    /opt/go/src/net/dial.go:591 +0xaa
net.Listen(0x123d330, 0x3, 0xc00014d860, 0x1b, 0x40d1d8, 0x7fbbab42d6c0, 0x0, 0x1)
    /opt/go/src/net/dial.go:674 +0x7e
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm.NewGRPCServer(0xc00014d860, 0x1b, 0x0, 0xc00049efc0, 0xc0005506c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm/server.go:50 +0xd8
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node.createChaincodeServer(0x13b01e0, 0xc00039a100, 0xc000044072, 0x16, 0x0, 0x1, 0x20, 0x2, 0xc0004a17a0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node/start.go:545 +0x482
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node.startChaincodeServer(0xc000044072, 0x16, 0x139c200, 0xc00037dec0, 0xc0003f39a0, 0xc0001ef900, 0x13a3260, 0xc0002c07f0, 0xc0001e7800, 0x3, ...)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node/start.go:743 +0x32f
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node.serve(0x1fc5e60, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node/start.go:267 +0xe79
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node.glob..func1(0x1eb3b00, 0x1fc5e60, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node/start.go:121 +0x9c
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x1eb3b00, 0x1fc5e60, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1eb3b00, 0x1fc5e60)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:762 +0x473
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x1eb4220, 0x8, 0x0, 0x1eb33e0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:852 +0x2fd
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0x1eb4220, 0xc00050ff40, 0x1)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:800 +0x2b
main.main()
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:53 +0x2f7

goroutine 51 [syscall]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0x0)
    /opt/go/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:139 +0x9c
os/signal.loop()
    /opt/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:23 +0x22
created by os/signal.init.0
    /opt/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:29 +0x41

goroutine 11 [IO wait]:
internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0x7fbba69bcf00, 0x72, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:173 +0x66
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc000154898, 0x72, 0xc000092500, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:85 +0x9a
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(0xc000154898, 0xffffffffffffff00, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:90 +0x3d
internal/poll.(*FD).Accept(0xc000154880, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:384 +0x1a0
net.(*netFD).accept(0xc000154880, 0x7fbbab42d6c0, 0x0, 0xc000460eb0)
    /opt/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:238 +0x42
net.(*TCPListener).accept(0xc0001446f8, 0xc000460eb8, 0x40d1d8, 0x30)
    /opt/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:139 +0x2e
net.(*TCPListener).Accept(0xc0001446f8, 0x1174aa0, 0xc00024c330, 0x1074180, 0x1ea5270)
    /opt/go/src/net/tcpsock.go:260 +0x47
net/http.(*Server).Serve(0xc0004360d0, 0x13b6a20, 0xc0001446f8, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/server.go:2826 +0x22f
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations.(*System).Start
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations/system.go:121 +0x1a3

goroutine 12 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc0000f08c0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x12a
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x177

goroutine 66 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc0000c0d00)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0xd3
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x40c

goroutine 67 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc0000c0d00)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:101 +0xe7
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:143 +0x42e

goroutine 68 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc0000c0d00)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:834 +0x331
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x58c

goroutine 69 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc0000c0d00)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:762 +0x12e
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x5ae

goroutine 70 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc0002ec000)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x12a
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x177

goroutine 82 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc0000c0ea0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0xd3
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x40c

goroutine 83 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc0000c0ea0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:101 +0xe7
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:143 +0x42e

goroutine 84 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc0000c0ea0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:834 +0x331
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x58c

goroutine 85 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc0000c0ea0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:762 +0x12e
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x5ae

goroutine 86 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc0002ec1c0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x12a
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x177

goroutine 87 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc0000c1040)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0xd3
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x40c

goroutine 88 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc0000c1040)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:101 +0xe7
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:143 +0x42e

goroutine 89 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc0000c1040)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:834 +0x331
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x58c

goroutine 90 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc0000c1040)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:762 +0x12e
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x5ae

goroutine 91 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc0002ec380)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x12a
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x177

goroutine 14 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc0000c11e0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0xd3
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x40c

goroutine 15 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc0000c11e0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:101 +0xe7
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:143 +0x42e

goroutine 16 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc0000c11e0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:834 +0x331
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x58c

goroutine 98 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc0000c11e0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:762 +0x12e
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x5ae

goroutine 99 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc0002ec460)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x12a
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x177

goroutine 100 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc0000c1380)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0xd3
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x40c

goroutine 101 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc0000c1380)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:101 +0xe7
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:143 +0x42e

goroutine 102 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc0000c1380)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:834 +0x331
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x58c

goroutine 103 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc0000c1380)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:762 +0x12e
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x5ae

goroutine 104 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc0002ec620)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x12a
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x177

goroutine 105 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc0000c1520)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0xd3
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x40c

goroutine 106 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc0000c1520)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:101 +0xe7
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:143 +0x42e

goroutine 107 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc0000c1520)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:834 +0x331
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x58c

goroutine 108 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc0000c1520)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:762 +0x12e
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x5ae

goroutine 133 [IO wait]:
internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0x7fbba69bce30, 0x72, 0xc000267a88)
    /opt/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:173 +0x66
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc000155098, 0x72, 0xffffffffffffff00, 0x13a05a0, 0x1ed6df0)
    /opt/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:85 +0x9a
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(0xc000155098, 0xc000213000, 0x1000, 0x1000)
    /opt/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:90 +0x3d
internal/poll.(*FD).Read(0xc000155080, 0xc000213000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:169 +0x179
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc000155080, 0xc000213000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xc000267b70, 0x45aa40, 0xc000000300)
    /opt/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:202 +0x4f
net.(*conn).Read(0xc00000e3d8, 0xc000213000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/net.go:177 +0x68
net/http.(*persistConn).Read(0xc0002aa6c0, 0xc000213000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xc000267c70, 0x405a35, 0xc000200a80)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1497 +0x75
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc0002e07e0)
    /opt/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:100 +0x10f
bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0xc0002e07e0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0xc00039c5a0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:132 +0x3f
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc0002aa6c0)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1645 +0x1a2
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /opt/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1338 +0x941

goroutine 134 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc0002aa6c0)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1885 +0x113
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /opt/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1339 +0x966

goroutine 42 [select]:
net.cgoLookupIP(0x13b79e0, 0xc000180880, 0xc00014d860, 0x16, 0x0, 0xa3e9e627abfd52, 0x4914cc9630d99f, 0x1d8a68c93, 0x0, 0x176199a651f0f2)
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:212 +0x17b
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP(0x1fa0d00, 0x13b79e0, 0xc000180880, 0xc00014d860, 0x16, 0x0, 0xc0000a0a80, 0xc000092040, 0xd119bc35a37e91, 0x3731fcea502374)
    /opt/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:95 +0x166
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP-fm(0x13b79e0, 0xc000180880, 0xc00014d860, 0x16, 0x42be22, 0x8, 0xc000092040, 0x65fb12980a82d3, 0xc000024ea0)
    /opt/go/src/net/lookup.go:207 +0x56
net.glob..func1(0x13b79e0, 0xc000180880, 0xc00034e490, 0xc00014d860, 0x16, 0x0, 0x0, 0x50112cacf28fa3, 0xb72986777935c1, 0x7df2c002387d89)
    /opt/go/src/net/hook.go:19 +0x52
net.(*Resolver).LookupIPAddr.func1(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/lookup.go:221 +0xd8
internal/singleflight.(*Group).doCall(0x1fa0d10, 0xc000316f50, 0xc00014d860, 0x16, 0xc000321290)
    /opt/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:95 +0x2e
created by internal/singleflight.(*Group).DoChan
    /opt/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:88 +0x2a0
```

says `peer.chaincodeListenAddress is not set, using peer0.org1.example.com:7052 fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x63 pc=0x7fa8ec127259]`. As shown above, peer0.org1.example.com container `Exited (2) 19 seconds ago`, so the container is not running.

I dont see any process blocking any port from 7000 to 7100 with `netstat -l`. Further, I dont know where the port 7052 come from. peer0.org1.example.com should run on `url: grpc://localhost:7051` according to `connection.yaml` from [fabric-samples/basic-network/connection.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples).

Any idea, why peer0.org1.example.com is not running?

Comment: Ran into this a couple of days ago after Fabric restarted forcefully (out of space). Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunetly, I dont have a solution for that. I tried to clarify my question. Cant post hole error trace because stack says its spam.

Comment: Just posted the hole stack trace.

Comment: Does your orderer container spin up 100% fine? This issue is similar to ours but for us, the orderer, which the peers depend on fails. hmm

Comment: Let me know if you find a solution to this. Will do the same back.

Comment: Same Problem! I tried downgrading go (because the official docs says fabric requires 1.11.x but it didn't resolve the issue)

Comment: @BenHayward As far as I can see, my orderer container spins up fine. The peer container just crashes.

Comment: @Jerry I dont think that is the problem. I just tried the same procedure on another ubuntu machine (go1.12)  and everything worked perfectly. Still dont know why it isnt working on my main ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 7):

for anyone who encountered this problem, I found a solution [here](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-13419). You just need to add the below env to your manifest

```
- GODEBUG=netdns=go
```

at the environment variable for orderer and peer.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution worked for me too.

Comment: you are a savior @DarwinHarianto.

Comment: My containers were going down as soon as they start. Tried various things and this is what seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Going to attempt to answer this. Sorry if it ends up being a waste of time!

One issue I was running into with the Peers was that for some reason /var/run/, which is the location used for the Peer had mounted as read only.

Try touch /var/run/test , and just see if you can write to it.

If not then you may have found your issue. As for the solution, you can either pick a new folder that you can write to, or change the permissions of the drive.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. I tried your approach but unfortunately it did not work for me. I solved this issue for myself by reinstalling ubuntu on my machine, set everything up again. I dont know where the issue in my last 5 setups was.

Answer (score -3):

Firstly stop the docker and then restart the docker . I think it will work