# Hyperledger Fabric peer container not coming up

Tags: docker, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperldger-fabric-peer

> Error:Get http://couchdb0:5984/: dial tcp 172.18.0.5:5984: connect:
>   connection refused

We are getting the above error in docker log of peer container. As a result peer containers are crashing. 
I have tried adding `dns_search: .` in `docker-compose.yaml` file.

```
  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    dns_search: .
```

I am running `RHEL 7` VM.

```
docker --version
Docker version 1.13.1, build 7f2769b/1.13.1
```

```
docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
```

Anything else I should look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue.
Needed to add below line under `envioronment:` in `docker-compose.yaml` file for `orderer` and `peer` containers.

```
- GODEBUG=netdns=go
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57246299/8507208)